# How to copy a BigQuery view via Python SDK?

Tags: python, view, google-bigquery

I have two BigQuery projects and I want to copy a view from Project 1 to Project 2:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
proj_1 = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(<path>, project='Project 1')
dataset_1 = proj_1.dataset(<dataset_name>)
view_1 = dataset_1.table(<view_name>)  # View to copy, already existing

proj_2 = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(<path>, project='Project 2')
dataset_2 = proj_2.dataset(<dataset_name>)
view_2 = dataset_2.table(<view_name>)  # Destination for copied view

# Start copy job like Google says
# https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#copyingtable
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: [{'message': 'Using table <project>:<dataset>.<view_name> is not allowed for this operation because of its type. Try using a different table that is of type TABLE.', 'reason': 'invalid'}]
```

I already know that if I set the attribute `view_query`, `view_2` will be recognized as a view. If I set it manually, it works. But the second (automated) solution does not, because the attribute `view_1.view_query` is always `None`.

```
view_2.view_query = 'SELECT * FROM ...'  # works
view_2.view_query = view_1.view_query    # Won't work, because view_1.view_query is always None
```

How can I access the query of view_1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call of `view_1.reload()` loads the attribute `view_query`.

See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery-usage.html

So

```
view_1.reload()
view_2.view_query = view_1.view_query
view_2.create()  # No need for a copy job, because there is no data copied
```

does the trick now.